# jquery mobile form's text element not properly rendered

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am novice to **jQuery Mobile** and now i am working with form element, I have write following code:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header"></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <input  type="text" placeholder="Enter some text"/>
         <input  type="password" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
        <input type="button" value="Login"  />
    </div>

</div>
```

but  design not properly rendered in above two input type.i don't know what is issue .
*below Picture shows ouput of above code ,in picture it is clearly displayed rendered view.*

[image: This is the design which is rendered while i run above code]

Comment: Hi! Please formulate a clear question on a specific problem, and you're more likely to get help. More details in the [FAQ].

Comment: thank you @David Parsson. My problem is that when i run above code i couldn't get proper output, there is extra margin is added in **input** type , i don't know how to remove that extra margin and view input textbox like [jqueryInputText](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/textinputs/) this jquery mobile site.

Comment: This code is fine. I don't see any problem. http://jsfiddle.net/dima_k/NMSG6/ Do you use some custom css?

Comment: Please check the file [Demo.html](https://app.box.com/s/116el0wbz0z2d9j43b4l) this is my demo page

Comment: No, I doesn't use any extra css in my project just uses jquery mobile css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dima Kuzmich I got my answer.
Actually I was using old version of jquery mobile css *1.2.0* of version, that's why it will render above image design.


but when i used latest version of jquery mobile css *1.3.1* then my issue is solved perfectly fine.

Thank you @Dima Kulmich.